# Search for input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

On my form, I store inputs in this way:

```
<input name="tokens[0][A]">
<input name="tokens[1][B]">
<input name="tokens[2][A]">
```

etc.

Is there a way, using javascript or jquery, to easily grab all the inputs with [A] as their final index? All I actually need to do is count the number of inputs with an [A] index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Ends With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("input[name$='[A]']")
```